# JAXL XMPP script works, but never stops loading

Tags: php, xmpp, facebook-chat

I am implementing the Facebook Chat into my site so I used JAXL in order to implement the XMPP. It seems that the script posts the message that I wanted, but whenever I run it, the page just keeps loading and loading and never stops. In order to get back onto that site, I have to clear the cookies for it in my browser. Not sure what the problem could be, I am not seeing any errors in my log. Take a look at the code: Thanks!

```
$client = new JAXL(array(
        'jid' => $user['facebookID']."@chat.facebook.com",
        'fb_app_key' => "XXXX",
        'fb_access_token' => $user['facebook_access_token'],
        'force_tls' => true,
        'auth_type' => 'X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM',
        'log_level' => JAXL_INFO,
        'priv_dir' => "includes/lib/jaxl/tmp"
    ));

    $client->add_cb('on_auth_success', function() {
        global $client;
        _info("got on_auth_success cb, jid ".$client->full_jid->to_string());
        $client->set_status("available!", "dnd", 10);

        $msg = new XMPPMsg(array('to'=>'-XXXX@chat.facebook.com'), 'test message');
        $client->send($msg);
    });

    $client->add_cb('on_auth_failure', function($reason) {
        global $client;
        $client->send_end_stream();
        _info("got on_auth_failure cb with reason $reason");
    });

    $client->add_cb('on_chat_message', function($stanza) {
        global $client;

        // echo back incoming message stanza
        $stanza->to = $stanza->from;
        $stanza->from = $client->full_jid->to_string();
        $client->send($stanza);
    });

    $client->add_cb('on_disconnect', function() {
        _info("got on_disconnect cb");
    });

    //
    // finally start configured xmpp stream
    //
    $client->start();

    echo "done";
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tested your code with a local jabber server.

I got the same result (page keeps loading) until I added a "$client->send_end_stream();" at the end of the on_auth_success function.

```
$client->add_cb('on_auth_success', function() {
    global $client;
    _info("got on_auth_success cb, jid ".$client->full_jid->to_string());
    $client->set_status("available!", "dnd", 10);

    $msg = new XMPPMsg(array('to'=>'-XXXX@chat.facebook.com'), 'test message');
    $client->send($msg);

    // Close the connection
    $client->send_end_stream();
});
```

It seems that the scripts supsends while no events occur.
Later the page times out.